# Set permissions to /bin/su

Tags: unix, permissions

I need to change my /bin/su permissions back to the default, which is

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 42436 2009-09-08 04:52 /bin/su
```

right now it's

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 42436 2009-09-08 04:52 /bin/su
```

How do I add the `s` in...? I've never seen that before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chmod u+s /bin/su` executed by `root`

Comment: +1 correct, and more information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid